# two different columns from two different ajax method how to combine into single row

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

HTML:

```
<table id="invoice">
   ....
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reports/fetch_invoice/",
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        "from_date": from_date,
        "to_date": to_date
    },
    success: function(data) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.invoice.length; i++) {
            var invoice = data.invoice[i]['invoice_id'];
            var tr = '';
            tr += '<tr><td>' + data.invoice[i]['emp_id'] +
                '</td><td>' + data.invoice[i]['invoice_id'] +
                '</td><td>' + data.invoice[i]['service'] +
                '</td>';
            $('#invoice').append(tr);

            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>reports/fetch_invoice_product/",
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    "invoice": invoice
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var total = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < data.product.length; i++) {
                        var tr = '';
                        total += parseInt(data.product[i]['total']);
                    }
                    tr += '<td>' + total +
                        '</td></tr>';

                    $('#invoice').append(tr);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

1st ajax method 3 columns in 1 row are append in table and 2nd ajax method 1row will be display that 1 row will be the 4th column of the 1st row in table.. How to do this??Please help..

Comment: why don't you get all data once with one url

Comment: because there are 2tables 1st table contain general info and 2nd table contain product info.Generally I am passing date that info contains in 1st table using date I am fetching invoice id using that invoice id I am fetching details from 2nd table

Comment: then you can use mysql jojn,or join all data in back-end,this will reduce requesting more xhr calls

Comment: In modal:                                                                                                       
   public function fetch_invoices($f_date,$t_date)
   {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('invoice');
    $this->db->join('invoice_products','invoice.invoice_id=invoice_products.invoice_id','outer');
    $this->db->where('date >=',$f_date);
    $this->db->where('date <=',$t_date);
    $res=$this->db->get();
    return $res->result();
  }  Whether this is correct??

Comment: use simple join for this `$this->db->query("SELECT * from invoice i join invoice_products ip ON ip.invoice_id=i.invoice_id WHERE date >= $f_date AND date <= $t_date")->result();`